# Error while retrieving user list under the group from active directory (System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement in C#)

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, active-directory

I am getting error while retrieving users under the group from active directory. Error description is 
{"Information about the domain could not be retrieved (1355)"}. Tried with .Net 4.0 and .Net 4.5.
The line for which I am getting the error is commented with the error message.

```
public List<DirectoryUser> GetUsersUnderGroup(string groupName)
    {
        var directoryUserList = new List<DirectoryUser>();
        string directoryServerIp="192.168.1.xxx";
        string ouName="xxxOuName";
        string domainComponents="DC=xxxComopnent1,DC=xxxComponent2";
        string directoryAdminUserId="directoryAdminuser";
        string directoryAdminPassword="directoryAdminPassword";
        using (var principalContext = principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, directoryServerIp, string.Format("OU={0},{1}", ouName, domainComponents), directoryAdminUserId, directoryAdminPassword);)
        {
            using (var group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, groupName))
            {
                if (group != null)
                {                       
                    var users = group.GetMembers(true);
                    //Works fine till the above line. variable users is having not null value but
                    //exception while iterating through the loop.Following is the exception
                    //{"Information about the domain could not be retrieved (1355)."}
                    foreach(var user in users)
                    {                            
                        Console.Write(user.DistinguishedName);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return directoryUserList;
    }
```

**Code for creating PrincipalContext is working fine in other scenarios (like fetching list of groups and OU's etc )**

Comment: Have you tried doing a Google search for "Information about the domain could not be retrieved (1355)"? Lots and lots of hits.

Comment: Tried some techniques like specifying ContextOptions E.g.ContextOptions.SimpleBind. Bud did not worked.

Answer (score 1):

This article describes reasons for your issue and possible solutions: [link](http://elegantcode.com/2009/03/21/one-scenario-where-the-systemdirectoryservices-accountmanagement-api-falls-down/). Basically, you have to use **DirectoryEntry** class if you run your code not from machine, where domain controller lies.
This article should help you to understand that class: [link](http://www.codemag.com/Article/1312041)